# Best way to only test for a condition if another condition is false

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

So I've got a function that uses an arraylist, and I want it to do something like this:

```
if(/*1*/ theArrayList.size() == 0 || /*2*/ theArrayList.get(someNumber).someBoolean){....
```

The problem is that this function can be triggered at a time when the ArrayList is empty, which would cause an error in the second half of the if statement. So I changed it to this:

```
if(theArrayList.size() == 0){
    //do some code
} else if(theArrayList.get(someNumber).someBoolean){
    //do the same code as above
} else...
```

But I feel like this is obtuse and that there must be an easier way. So how can I make it only test for the second half of the if statement if the first half has already been proven false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not actually cause an error on the second half of the if statement. You're using || which is a short-circuit OR. That means that if the first part is true (the array list is empty) then the second part will not be evaluated.

Comment: Well, that's what I was doing earlier and I kept getting errors. I tried it again, tho, and it worked just fine. Guess I'm just a dumbass lol. Thanks :)

Comment: You could be getting errors if someNumber does not exist in theArrayList. For stronger code, I might go with:  if(theArrayList.size() == 0 || (theArrayList.get(someNumber) != null && theArrayList.get(someNumber).someBoolean))